# Exporting data from multiple lists

Tags: sharepoint, moss

I need to export data from multiple document libraries in sharepoint 2007. The data is stored in many thousands libraries across a few sites. All libraries have identical columns definitions and usually contain only a small number of documents each.

I am using sharepoint services.
First calling GetListCollection() to get all lists from the site, and the call GetListItems() for every single document library.

The process of querying each library separately is very slow and time consuming.
Is there a way to get all data from multiple document lists in a single call?

Answer (score 0):

A SPSiteDataQuery may be of use to you. Have a google around it and see if this would help you. The lists would have to be of the same type though

CAML would certainly increase performance.

Cheers

Truez

Comment: To use SPSiteDataQuery you must have a common **content type** across all the list from you want to fetch data.

Comment: Thanks. I am using webservices, not the API. Is there a way to use the SPSiteDataQuery  functionality through the sharepoint web services?